# Server workload increase during php image resize

Tags: php, apache, optimization, image-processing

i have a php script that resize image to three different resolutions on upload. When i upload a image it resizes it to 300*300, 80*80, 800*800 and also saves the original file.

The script that i use is the following link https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/example/upload.php

the following images is the system monitor of the server. The first two spikes of CPU history the resize of the image that takes place when the file is uploaded individually. The following are the files that are uploaded from a queue.

[image: CPU WORKLOAD]

During this upload the server couldn't handle other requests. i cannot able to access other pages at that time. either the page loads half or doesn't load at all or the page loads once the upload is complete.

i need immediate  solution to this problem. how to overcome this issue. i have to full for the server. is there any pluggin  for apache for image resize or is there a problem with the code.

Comment: How large are the original files?

Comment: If you're running this on a local, personal test machine, with the specs you have, it's unlikely the server will be able to handle a huge amount, especially as it's also running GNOME, etc. You should try this on a "proper" server and see if it still hangs.

Comment: And how many server do you own? Server specs?

Comment: Buy another server. More powerful.

Comment: This one is Intel Pentium Dual CPU @ 1.60GHz and my laptop which is Intel Core i7 2nd Gen @ 2.00GHz which also pretty much get heavy load. now am trying imagemagick and ill 
try the solution given by arnaud576875 and ill let you all know..!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even if resizing an image took 100% of CPU during a minute, it would still be possible to do other requests: you are using a multi-processes server on a multitasking operating system (and probably with multiple cores too).

However, when you start a PHP session, **the session is locked**: other requests trying to use the same session have to **wait until the first request ends**.

This is why you can't do concurrent requests while the image is being resized.

You have to close your session before doing long processing (and eventually re-open it after that).

So, this should fix your problem:

```
session_write_close();
resize_the_image();
session_start();
```

Comment: This would only affect the single user that is uploading, a user from another computer /  browser would not be affected.

Comment: OP said that **himself** cannot access other pages during image resizing. He didn't mentioned that other users are affected at the same time.

Comment: "the session is locked" - only on MS Window$

Comment: @symcbena: this is the case on every operating system with the default session handler; the session file is locked with flock() right after it's opened. (source: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/11526999d832227a0a1b24fcb96112e3c03c6426/ext/session/mod_files.c#L187)

Comment: Yeah, I know that he said that, I just clarified that. He should test with another browser just to test if it only affects the session and not the whole site (all visitors).

Comment: @arnaud576875 **yes you are right**.. i just tested it.. and it works perfectly in other computers... thanks man... but what if multiple users uploads at same time then CPU would take more time to process the request right..!!

Comment: Yes, more requests means slower requests too. Try different image libraries to see if it helps; and buy a new CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ImageMagick to resize instead of the normal PHP functions, that might take the load off a bit.

Answer (score 0):

> During this upload the server couldn't handle other requests

I find that very surprising, particularly given that there are 2 cores (although you don't say what operating system / webserver you are using). If it's only the image upload functionality which is affected then I suspect that it may be due to issues within your PHP script.

Certainly it may be possible to reduce the amount of load generated by the server during processing. Most of these would involve starting a new compiled process (e.g. via exec) to process the image e.g. from the [imageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) utilities bundle - but without knowing what OS this is, it's impossible to give more specific advice.

In terms of reducing the impact of image conversion, I'd run a managed queue for the incoming images to be processed by. This would ensure you've only got the image handling running on a single core.